# Hold payment from one stripe account to other stripe account

Tags: php, stripe-payments, react-native-stripe-api

Here, I am using Stripe APIs for payment gateway.
There is no requirement to make payment through bank account to stripe account and vise-versa.
That's why I am making payment with one stripe account to other stripe account.

This process I have done with "https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers" that is complete working.

I have done all the functionality but main question is as below.

**Question:**

Can I hold payment in between from one stripe account to other stripe account?

For e.g. If one user is making payment from stripe account, the balance should be deduct.
But when I want to release that payment, then other user will get that balance.

In between is it possible to make the payment in hold?

Suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, after some research and some implementation, there is process to hold the funds by using `Charge` API with `capture` parameter that is related to bank account.

But there is no any API to `capture` or hold the funds from one stripe account to other stripe account because stripe is not a wallet service.